# Meteor.js - global events on server?

Tags: node.js, meteor

Does Meteor.js have a way to emit global events on the server ? Eg

```
// how to set make myEmitter available across files/packages ?
myEmitter = new Npm.require('events').EventEmitter;

if(Meteor.isServer){

Meteor.methods({
    'foo' : function(){
        myEmitter.emit('fooEvent', { 'bar' : 'hello!'});
    }
});
}
```

and

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
    function doFoo(){
        console.log('Foo done !');
    }
    myEmitter.on('fooEvent', doFoo);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work. Just change this line:

```
myEmitter = new Npm.require('events').EventEmitter;
```

to

```
myEmitter = new (Npm.require('events').EventEmitter);
```

You shouldn't have to use a package this because EventEmitter is part of nodejs core.

To make it available to the other files just don't use the `var` keyword.

If you're using this in a package you have to make sure you use `api.export` in your `package.js` to export it out to the rest of the app.

Answer (score 2):

Meteor doesn't have a built-in event emitter.  However, it does allow you to use npm modules, like the one in your example code.

You'll need to add the npm package to your app.  See it's [documentation](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/npm) on atmosphere for details.